# How do I type "too" instead of "to" using the new Swipe-style keyboard

Tags: 8.1, wordflow

When using the swipe-style of input that is available as part of the 8.1 update, how do I enter the word "too" instead of "to"?  The best I've come up with is to swipe from the "t" to the "o", then click "too" in the suggestion bar, but don't feel that's optimal - I'd much rather swipe "too" directly somehow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can swipe consecutive letters by making an uninterrupted "circle" motion on the letter that needs to be duplicated. This may take some practice, but once you get used to it, is fairly intuitive.

Comment: Nice! You're right, it does take some practice. You also have to be careful not to swipe over the neighbouring letters, but once you get the hang of it, it works pretty well.

Comment: Actually I somewhat memorized that is the second option in the suggestion and it stopped bother me.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a circle.  It can be sort of a little jiggle, like a small up-down motion on the letter.

Comment: @Kyralessa good to know, i just knew the circle motion worked.

Comment: It seems that just pausing on the letter for a little bit also works.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know, this dictionary is "learning" - if you use "too" more than "to", it will automatically type the most used one. But there is no such an option in phone that allows you to customize this.